# Can I access private api's via JMeter

Tags: api, jmeter-4.0

I am almost finalizing JMeter for my performance testing on cloud software (salesforce).
we do have certain private api's. Will it be possible to access those via JMeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure you are executing your test in the same network and you have the access to the gateway to test the private API's with correct credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as you have the correct credentials to access the environment.